# Git - Commit, branching and merging gives unexpected behaviour

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Recently I've started working with Git at my company and I'm noticing something strange and I cannot figure out what is going on under the hood.

So for the workflow we have a repository and the policy is that we have to make a branch whenever we want to work on the project, which is fairly straight forward and it makes sense.

The issue I'm experiencing is whenever I'm done working in a branch i stage whatever is left and push my final commit, then I create a pull request and it has to pass code review before the merge.

However, when the pull request is approved and the changes merged to master I want to delete my branch locally (as it is auto deleted when merging on origin anyway). This is actually not so straight forward as I would expect.

What happens is that if I attempt to delete my branch or checkout another branch, git will prevent me because it wants me to know that I have changes not staged for commit. This is the part that makes no sense to me, everything I've done has been commited, reviewed and merged, so what are these changes?

What I've done so far is use "git add ". Now I can inspect it, to see what kind of changes has been made here, since it says It contains changes. This is the second weird thing, there is no changes at all.

So for the time being I'm resolving these issues manually, but it gets time consuming when I have to do this with every branch. Have I missed something obvious? Am I doing something wrong?

This happend again today, although slightly different, but the end result was the same. I had finished a feature, cleaned up the branch (no issues with that today), so what I wanted to do when that feature branch was deleted, was to checkout master and pull changes to ensure I was at the latest revision and then what I wrote above happend in master. I had all latest changes, yet git was telling me I had unstaged changes (again no changes at all when inspecting these files).

**Minor update:** git status -u only says that my branch is up to date with origin/HEAD and that I have unstaged changes (listing those files) and that's about it, again hidden from Visual Studio Code changes section. The only choices I have is to stage them ("git add", making them visible in the editor) or discard them (git checkout "file name").

gitignore:

```
# See https://help.github.com/ignore-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# compiled output
/dist/
/tmp/

# dependencies
/bower_components/
/node_modules/

# misc
/.sass-cache
/connect.lock
/coverage/
/libpeerconnection.log
/npm-debug.log*
/testem.log
/yarn-error.log

# ember-try
/.node_modules.ember-try/
/bower.json.ember-try
/package.json.ember-try

## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
##
## Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore
# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates
# User-specific files (MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio)
*.userprefs
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
[Ll]og/
# Visual Studio 2015/2017 cache/options directory
.vs/
# Uncomment if you have tasks that create the project's static files in wwwroot
#wwwroot/
# Visual Studio 2017 auto generated files
Generated\ Files/
# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
# NUNIT
*.VisualState.xml
TestResult.xml
# Build Results of an ATL Project
[Dd]ebugPS/
[Rr]eleasePS/
dlldata.c
# Benchmark Results
BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts/
# .NET Core
project.lock.json
project.fragment.lock.json
artifacts/
**/Properties/launchSettings.json
# StyleCop
StyleCopReport.xml
# Files built by Visual Studio
*_i.c
*_p.c
*_i.h
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.iobj
*.pch
*.pdb
*.ipdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.svclog
*.scc
*.sqlite
# Chutzpah Test files
_Chutzpah*
# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opendb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile
*.VC.db
*.VC.VC.opendb
# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx
*.sap
# Visual Studio Trace Files
*.e2e
# TFS 2012 Local Workspace
$tf/
# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState
# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper
*.DotSettings.user
# JustCode is a .NET coding add-in
.JustCode
# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*
# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover
# AxoCover is a Code Coverage Tool
.axoCover/*
!.axoCover/settings.json
# Visual Studio code coverage results
*.coverage
*.coveragexml
# NCrunch
_NCrunch_*
.*crunch*.local.xml
nCrunchTemp_*
# MightyMoose
*.mm.*
AutoTest.Net/
# Web workbench (sass)
.sass-cache/
# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/
# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html
# Click-Once directory
publish/
# Publish Web Output
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.azurePubxml
# Note: Comment the next line if you want to checkin your web deploy settings,
# but database connection strings (with potential passwords) will be unencrypted
*.pubxml
*.publishproj
# Microsoft Azure Web App publish settings. Comment the next line if you want to
# checkin your Azure Web App publish settings, but sensitive information contained
# in these scripts will be unencrypted
PublishScripts/
# NuGet Packages
*.nupkg
# The packages folder can be ignored because of Package Restore
**/[Pp]ackages/*
# except build/, which is used as an MSBuild target.
!**/[Pp]ackages/build/
# Uncomment if necessary however generally it will be regenerated when needed
#!**/[Pp]ackages/repositories.config
# NuGet v3's project.json files produces more ignorable files
*.nuget.props
*.nuget.targets
# Microsoft Azure Build Output
csx/
*.build.csdef
# Microsoft Azure Emulator
ecf/
rcf/
# Windows Store app package directories and files
AppPackages/
BundleArtifacts/
Package.StoreAssociation.xml
_pkginfo.txt
*.appx
# Visual Studio cache files
# files ending in .cache can be ignored
*.[Cc]ache
# but keep track of directories ending in .cache
!*.[Cc]ache/
# Others
ClientBin/
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.dbproj.schemaview
*.jfm
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
orleans.codegen.cs
# Including strong name files can present a security risk 
# (https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/2483#issue-259490424)
#*.snk
# Since there are multiple workflows, uncomment next line to ignore bower_components
# (https://github.com/github/gitignore/pull/1529#issuecomment-104372622)
#bower_components/
# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/
# Backup & report files from converting an old project file
# to a newer Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed,
# because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm
ServiceFabricBackup/
*.rptproj.bak
# SQL Server files
*.mdf
*.ldf
*.ndf
# Business Intelligence projects
*.rdl.data
*.bim.layout
*.bim_*.settings
*.rptproj.rsuser
# Microsoft Fakes
FakesAssemblies/
# GhostDoc plugin setting file
*.GhostDoc.xml
# Node.js Tools for Visual Studio
.ntvs_analysis.dat
node_modules/
# Visual Studio 6 build log
*.plg
# Visual Studio 6 workspace options file
*.opt
# Visual Studio 6 auto-generated workspace file (contains which files were open etc.)
*.vbw
# Visual Studio LightSwitch build output
**/*.HTMLClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.DesktopClient/ModelManifest.xml
**/*.Server/GeneratedArtifacts
**/*.Server/ModelManifest.xml
_Pvt_Extensions
# Paket dependency manager
.paket/paket.exe
paket-files/
# FAKE - F# Make
.fake/
# JetBrains Rider
.idea/
*.sln.iml
# CodeRush
.cr/
# Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS)
__pycache__/
*.pyc
# Cake - Uncomment if you are using it
# tools/**
# !tools/packages.config
# Tabs Studio
*.tss
# Telerik's JustMock configuration file
*.jmconfig
# BizTalk build output
*.btp.cs
*.btm.cs
*.odx.cs
*.xsd.cs
# OpenCover UI analysis results
OpenCover/
# Azure Stream Analytics local run output 
ASALocalRun/
# MSBuild Binary and Structured Log
*.binlog
# NVidia Nsight GPU debugger configuration file
*.nvuser
# MFractors (Xamarin productivity tool) working folder 
.mfractor/
/.vscode
```

Comment: Some `git status` or `git status -u` output and the contents of your `.gitignore` file would be helpful. The parts of your description that make no sense to you are indeed not the expected behaviour, but without some concrete output it's impossible to say what's going on.

Comment: @kowsky I've updated my original post with an update to git status -u and provided the contents of the project's gitignore.

Comment: `...and that I have unstaged changes (listing those files)` Which files? Are these files not part of your work?

Comment: @kowsky They were. It's listing files I've been making changes to, but these files have already been commited and merged, this is what is so puzzling to me. They should not be there, and when i diff them there are no diff at all, yet I have to make a decision, discard or add. Up until now I always discard them.

Comment: Where `git status` show you have unstages changes, `git diff` should tell you what those changes are. If you're on Windows, maybe you have a Unix vs Windows newline format conflict? A shotgun solution: `git reset --hard` will revert all changes at once, whatever they are. Use with care: it cannot be undone!

Comment: PS: make sure your diff is not done with `-b` or `-w`, which would hide the whitespace issue I'm speculating could be your problem.

Comment: @joanis Thanks for your reply! I think you were right, I've added an gitattributes file to specify the "core.autocrlf" for our repository. So far so good, but I'm gonna have to do some more work in branches to say for sure if it worked or not.

Comment: @Syntone OK, thanks for letting me know. I'll write it up as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

1) Make sure you do the `git diff` without `-b` or `-w` and with `core.autocrlf=false`.

2) You can reset all the changed files at once with `git reset --hard` if you're sure you have no further changes you want to commit.

**Details**

*Diff*

When `git status` and `git diff` disagree on what files are changes, it can be due to whitespace issues, especially newline styles if you are working on Windows.

For example, I did this test on Windows:

- Change file `a` from Linux newline to Windows-style CRLF
- `git status` says `a` is changed (regardless of `core.autocrlf` settings)
- `git diff` shows the change in `a` when `core.autocrlf=false`
- `git diff` shows not changes at all when `core.autocrlf=true`
- similarly, `git diff -b` and `git diff -w` show no changes.

*Reset*

Now, if you know you have no changes of value in your sandbox, e.g., all the changes are due to line-endings, you can reset the whole sandbox to the state in `HEAD` with this command:

```
git reset --hard
```

Be warned: this is destructive and cannot be undone. Any changes to files in your sandbox will be lost for good.